# Class Hierarchy 

Tags: c++

Please don't mind about the syntax. I thought of making the post as brief as possible.

We have a class hierarchy as below.

```
// abstract class.   
class BaseProd   
// concrete classes.   
class Prod1 : public BaseProd   
class Prod2 : public BaseProd   
class Prod3 : public BaseProd
```

Each class has 3 sub classes like, Prod1New, Prod1Cancel and Prod1Modify the same case for the other 2 classes. Now, since New, Cancel and Modify are the events, we can represent them using enum.

The problem is, each class has lot of methods that are very specific to each event. Eg.

```
getRec(); // has specific implementations for each event.
```

Let's say there is something like process method.

```
void Prod1::process()
{
   getRec(); // Each derived class overrides the method.   
   getPayment();// Each derived class overrides the method.   
}
```

This way, we have 13 classes for 3 products having 3 events each.
If we have 2 more products the classes would grow by 8.

Can we have any alternate approach to this hierarchy?

UPDATE:
The suggestion made by Tyler works only when 
Prod1's NewEvent and Prod2's NewEvent have the same implementation. Right? But in this case it is not. Atleast for some of the methods it is not.

Comment: Yes.... you definitely should take a different approach. Why do you need even need a different class for each Product? Are they that significantly different (have different properties/methods) or do they only have different values (like name and price)? Why do you need "Modify", and "New" classes for each product? Can't you make those things methods inside the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why the New, Cancel, and Modify messages should be subclasses of the products that they apply to. This doesn't satisfy the "is-a" relationship that should define inheritance. If class `D` inherits from class `B`, the statement "Every `D` is a `B`" should make sense and always be true. "A `Prod1` is a `BaseProd`" (i.e. "Every specific product is a product") -- that is true and makes sense.

But in the case of events, a `Prod1Cancel` is **not** a `Prod1`. It doesn't make sense to say "Every product1 cancellation event is a product1." Rather, a `Prod1Cancel` is an event *relating to* `Prod1`, so it makes more sense that the `Prod1Cancel` class should *contain* a `Prod1` object, rather than inheriting from it.

Since all of your products inherit from a `BaseProd` class, you should really only need one class for each event, and not one class per event per product type, if you define your event classes like this:

```
class NewProductEvent {

   public:

     explicit NewProductEvent(BaseProd* product)
       : m_product(product)
     { /* ... */ }

     void getRec() { /* ... */ }
     void getPayment() { /* ... */ }

   private:

     BaseProd* m_product; // Use this to access the data that the event 
                          // needs from the product
};
```

Then, inside your `Prod1::process()` method, you could generate a `NewProductEvent` event for the current object, and call the appropriate methods on it:

```
void Prod1::process()
{
  NewProductEvent event(this);

  event.getRec();
  event.getPayment();
}
```

Comment: This works when Prod1's NewEvent and Prod2's NewEvent have the same implementation. Right? But in this case it is not. Atleast for some of the methods it is not.

Comment: Then you could put the functionality that differs between products into virtual methods in `BaseProd` that are overridden and implemented by the individual product classes, and call those methods from the event class. e.g. if each product has a different means of calculating its price, then you could have a virtual `getPrice()` method in `ProdBase` and then the event class could invoke `m_product->getPrice()` to use the product-specific implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Make a strategy class for each event and inject it into the Prod class at runtime.

```
class BaseProd
{
   public BaseProd(EventStrategy event) : _event(event);
   private EventStrategy _event;

   virtual public void Process();
}

void Prod1::process()
{
  _event.getRec(); // Each derived class overrides the method.   
  _event.getPayment();// Each derived class overrides the method.      
}
```

Now you can subclass EventStrategy and overrode getRec(), getPayment(), etc. And of course override process() too.

Comment: +1 Good suggestion! This looks like the inversion of my answer, creating a class for each product-event and then only a single class for all products. This would be the best idea if the OP's program were oriented around managing and processing *events*, while mine makes more sense if the program is oriented around managing and processing *products*. It's not clear which of these is the case, from the question.

Comment: @Tyler: It's oriented around managing and processing products. That's the reason I selected yours.